# Outlook MailItem delete making outlook to hang

Tags: c#, outlook, mailitem

I am trying to delete a mailitem in outlook using c# (Outlook addin)

I am getting mailitem from advancesearch.

**Deleting mail Item**

```
mail.Delete();
```

**Moving mailitem to DeletedItems Folder**

```
Outlook.MailItem mailitem = mail.Move(deleteditemFolder);
if (mailitem != null)
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailitem );
    mailitem = null;
}
```

Both the Implementation is making my outlook to hang for few seconds ..

How can i avoid outlook hang ? This there any ways ?

I am using outlook 2010 version .

Comment: Is that an online or a cached (OST) profile?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko  it is not an OST .Online profile .

Comment: Does the problem go away if you turn the cached mode on?